# How to disable UI keyboard keys for swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to disable all keyboard keys except for numbers and the decimal point. Everything works fine for iphone or ipod, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the decimal pad only keyboard for ipad (probably because it doesn't exist). In my textFields it should only have numbers or decimals otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Make your view controller a `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:,replacementString)`. The method should return `false` if the user has entered invalid characters.

Comment: Awesome thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set `keyboardType` number like this:

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Comment: This will not disable the alphabetic keyboard on an iPad.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct that would work perfect, but not for iPad. I figured out a work around by only allowing certain entries into the keyboard. Thank you.